# Counting all properties of an object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I basically need to count the tags 'property1' and 'property2' such that the result comes out to be 4.
The object looks somewhat like this:

```
parent: {
  child: {
    child2: {
      child3: { property1: '', property2: '' }
    }
  },
  2child: {
    2child2: {
      2child3: { property1: '', property2: '' }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to count the specified properties but can't find a way to do so. The object can have many such child objects with their own child objects and all specified properties need to be counted.
My first guess would be that recursion will be required.

Comment: You're guessing very well :-)

Comment: That is invalid object notation.

Comment: In your example, do you only want to count 'property1', 'property2' in each child, such that the correct number is 4, or do you recognize that to Javascript each of those object keys is effectively a 'property', meaning that the total is going to be 10?

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. I basically need the specified properties to be counted such that the answer becomes 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use a recursive function. Also the methods `Object.keys` and `Object.values` will be useful:

```js
function propCount(obj) {
    return Object(obj) !== obj ? 0
         : Object.values(obj).map(propCount)
                 .reduce( (a,b) => a+b, Object.keys(obj).length );
}

var obj = {parent: {child: {child2: {child3: { property1: '', property2: '' }}},"2child": {"2child2": {"2child3": { property1: '', property2: '' }}}}};

console.log(propCount(obj));
```

Comment: Hey man, he was able to solve it himself! Just give some time haha :P nice answer nonetheless.

Comment: `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` fails on strings and returns a char array rather than just one object. Try to change one of the properties to a string rather than the empty string, then you will get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @Pavlo, fixed that. Thanks for reporting it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple scenario you might follow:

- Call `Object.keys(...)` on the root object
- For each key, check if the value is another object. If so, recurse.
- If it's not an object, move on to the next key.
- For each key, increment a counter.

You can do all these steps in a small function with less than 10 lines of code. Try it out and let me know if you need any help! :)